# not able to run digitize2d for a more than image

Tags: r

I would to digitize two dimensional landmarks from a set of images jpg. 
I set the the folder containing all the images as working directory.
Then I created a file list

```
pics <- list.files(pattern = "*jpg")
```

and then I used the function digitize2d on pics

```
digitize2d("pics", nlandmarks = 4, scale=1, tpsfile = "dig_pics", verbose = TRUE)
```

but I get this error:

> Digitizing specimen 1 in filelist  Error in readJPEG(filelist[i],
>   native = T) : unable to open pics

I dont understand why, as I followed the tutorial. Can anybody help? 
If I use the function on one image it works, but doing it one by one it is really time consuming. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pics` should not be quoted...

Comment: yes, I saw it then, thanks!